# How to identify the REAL Drafts folder on a IMAP server?

Tags: imap

I don’t know how trivial this question is, but I’ve been thinking on this a lot.
How do I find the REAL Drafts folder on an IMAP server?
For Gmail and AOL, I could see there is some mapping in the response which will help me find out the server’s draft folder.
But for lot of others server, including Yahoo.com, it seems there is no proper and consistent way to find the server’s Drafts folder.
Few flavors of Drafts folder name:
Draft
Drafts
INBOX.Drafts

Please suggest a way to find it out.

Answer (score 5):

For generic servers, what is the Drafts folder is only a matter of convention.  There is no "official" Sent Folder, Drafts Folder, Trash Folder, etc.  Email Clients tend to use a fairly small set of names, and thus you can guess heuristically.  A folder at the top level, or a child of the INBOX named "Drafts" is likely to be used as the Drafts folder by many clients.

As you've noticed, some servers support [RFC 6514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154%5D) to some level or another to help mitigate this problem.  If your server supports LIST extensions, then you can be sure that the folder marked \Drafts is the drafts folder.  Otherwise, you must fall back to guessing.

Comment: Thanks Max. Although your answer addresses my doubt to a large extent, but still I have some doubts about it. For example Yahoo.com publishes their draft folder as "Draft". A user can creates a folder named "Drafts" under inbox. In this case which draft folder should we consider. Is their any priority kind of thing.

Comment: If some other client doesn't support 6514, it may still make it's own Drafts folder.  Normally, email clients are configurable with regards to their special folders.

Comment: I am not clear on this. I will rephrase my doubt. If a mail provider has "Draft", "Drafts" and "INBOX.Drafts"  folder. Then while syncing the folders which drafts folder should I consider as real draft folder? Is there any priority i have to set to certain names?

Comment: You simply cannot know beforehand which folder you need to use, as different clients may create their own version of a Draft/Drafts/etc folder.